# Stored Procedure Returning False in vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

I'm having an issue with my vb.net program. The issue is coming from my stored procedure classes. I have tested the stored procedures in the SQL database I'm working with, and all of them are working.

I also want to note that I did copy and paste the SP's name over to the SQL server and executed it and it ran perfectly.

```
EXEC dbo.ksp_Get_Available_Statuses
```

In the program itself only one SP class is working. The following is that code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Add_Term
    Public Function addTerm(ByVal term As String, ByVal definitionSource As Integer, ByVal formatNote As String, ByVal definition As String, ByVal authorization As String, ByVal addReason As String)
        Dim connection As SqlConnection = DataConnection.getProperityDBConnection

        Dim insertCommand As New SqlCommand("dbo.ksp_Add_Term", connection)
        insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", term)
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@definitionSource", definitionSource)
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@formatNote", formatNote)
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@definition", definition)
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authorization", authorization)
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addReason", addReason)

    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim count As Integer = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If count > 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
 End Function
End Class
```

Here is the code I'm working on fixing, but it's not working. I don't see what I'm doing wrong and it's driving me nuts. I need a second pair (if not more) eyes on it.
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

```
Public Class Get_Avaliable_Statuses
    Public Function getAvailableStatuses()
        Dim connection As SqlConnection = DataConnection.getProperityDBConnection

        Dim insertCommand As New SqlCommand("dbo.ksp_Get_Available_Statuses", connection)
        insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Try
            connection.Open()
            Dim count As Integer = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If count > 0 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch e As Exception
            Throw e
        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

The following is the error that is popping up for those that want to know the exact wording: 
[Error Message Screen Shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqE4m.png)
As allows, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the two procs are in the same database. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847879/could-not-find-stored-procedure).

Comment: Yes. Both SPs are using the same dataconnection class. Both of them work in the SQL server, but only one of them works in the code. I have no idea why it keeps returning the second SP as false. It has rows with results in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supervisor looked over my code to assist. Realized it should be Excute Reader and not ExecuteNonQuery. I'm looking for information, not inserting new sources.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

do you have a

```
set nocount on
```

in your sproc? I guess ExecuteNonQuery cannot return the number of affected rows then ...

Comment: Boss looked over my code. Found it was supposed to read 
    ExecuteReader

instead of 
    ExecuteNonQuery.

Thank you for the help though!