# Could not find stored procedure 'exec _bspWhUtilAddAllStkToWh 2'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've developed the following script:

```
declare @query  nvarchar(1000)
declare @Loop   int

declare @Whse table
    (   ID  int identity primary key
    ,   WhseLink    int)

    insert into @Whse
    (   WhseLink    )
    select WhseLink from WhseMst

    select @Loop = min(ID) from @Whse
    while @Loop is not null

    begin
        set @query  = 'exec _bspWhUtilAddAllStkToWh('+cast((select WhseLink from @Whse where ID = @Loop) as varchar)+')'
        exec @query
        select @Loop = min(ID) from @Whse where ID>@Loop
    end
```

Based on the above, I get the following Error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'exec _bspWhUtilAddAllStkToWh 2'

I've checked the following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847879/could-not-find-stored-procedure) which the user also had the same problem, but I think this one is different to that, due to the fact that the Stored Procedure actually exists and when I run the same script separately, it works.

I've tried adding brackets so that the @query eventually looks like this : 'exec (_bspWhUtilAddAllStkToWh) 2', but I still receive the same error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you need to perhaps preface that proc name with a database name?

Comment: `exec (@query)`?

Comment: Wow! I didn't think of that. It works now! Thanks HoneyBadger!

Comment: You can use `sp_executesql` to pass parameter values to the stored procedure without string concatenation

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql in the first place? It is completely unnecessary here. And you should ALWAYS specify a length of varchars. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should avoid looping at all costs. In your situation I would consider changing your procedure to receive a table valued function so you can receive a whole collection of Warehouse Links and do whatever is in your procedure on the entire set. But assuming you can't do that you can use a cursor here and forget the dynamic sql because it isn't needed.

Something like this is a lot simpler.

```
declare @WarehouseLink int
declare Warehouses cursor local fast_forward 
for
    select WhseLink 
    from WhseMst

fetch next from Warehouses into @WarehouseLink

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
begin
    exec _bspWhUtilAddAllStkToWh @WarehouseLink

    fetch next from Warehouses into @WarehouseLink
end
```

Comment: Brilliant! I will use it!