# "Could not find stored procedure" error when called from C# application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure in SQL Server and tried calling it from my C# application but I am getting a message

> Could not find stored procedure

I have already tried all possible solutions from ["could not find stored procedure"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847879/could-not-find-stored-procedure)

Here is the definition of my stored procedure (created successfully)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].TagSaveToDblogic 
    @epcid NVARCHAR(100),
    @antid INTEGER,
    @starttime DATETIME,
    @endtime DATETIME,
    @sigstr INTEGER,
    @locid INTEGER,
    @valid INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LAST_LOCID int

    SELECT @LAST_LOCID = [LAST_LOCATION]
    FROM [DocumentTracking].[dbo].[KAWS_CARIBONI_DT_TAGS] 
    WHERE TAG_ID = @epcid

    IF (@LAST_LOCID != @locid)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [DocumentTracking].[dbo].[KAWS_CARIBONI_DT_TEER] (EPC_DOCUMENT_CODE, ANTENNA_ID, READ_START_TIMESTAMP, READ_END_TIMESTAMP, SIGNAL_STRENGTH, LOCATION_ID, VALID_ENTRY) 
        VALUES (@epcid, @antid, @starttime, @endtime, @sigstr, @locid, @valid)
    END
END
```

Here is a screenshot of the SELECT from sysobjects table where type = 'P' and category = 0
https://ibb.co/x2vFQzw

This is my complete code to call the stored procedure from the C# application:

```
string connetionString = null;
connetionString = "Data Source=192.9.100.250;Initial Catalog=DocumentTracking;User ID=alstom;Password=";

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connetionString);
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.TagSaveToDblogic", connection);

command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@epcid", row[2].ToString());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@antid", m_curInventoryBuffer.nCurrentAnt);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starttime", m_curInventoryBuffer.dtStartInventory);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endtime", m_curInventoryBuffer.dtEndInventory);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sigstr", (Convert.ToInt32(row[4]) - 129));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locid", 1);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valid", 1);

connection.Open();
int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The last line of the code is where I get the error.

Please help me resolve this error!

Comment: Are you sure that this sproc is created within the DocumentTracking database? If so check if the user alstom has permissions for it

Comment: It's suspicious that your stored procedure repeats the database name explicitly. Ensure it is created in the correct database (i.e. put a `USE DocumentTracking` / `GO` at the beginning) and you could and arguably should remove the database name from the objects in the sproc itself, as otherwise it would needlessly break if the DB is renamed.

Comment: Also, try without the `dbo.`, and a couple of important notes: 1. SqlCommand and SqlConnection are disposable, use the `using` statement when using them. 2. Don't use `AddWithValue`.

Comment: Also ensure that the user `alstom` has rights to execute the procedure.  SQL Server has Catalog Security, and so you can't even _see_ objects you don't have any rights to.

Comment: @DmitriTsoy I am sure about this because this is the only existing database. Rechecked Alstom permissions. All good there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Okay let me ass USING statement. But note that I have only one database.

Comment: If you're on SQL Server, you always have at least the system databases as well, and by default connections start off in `master`, so it's fairly easy to end up with objects in the wrong place. If that's not the problem, then per the rest, you have a permission issue, and you need to `GRANT EXECUTE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @DimitryTsoy and @JeroenMostert

Adding the following statements did the trick:

```
USE DocumentTracking
GO
```

DocumentTracking is the database name.

Comment: So you accidentally created your procedure on the wrong database?

Comment: I guess so. I wrongly assumed that DocumentTracking will be used by default since I opened a query editor for that database.

Comment: You can change (and should always check) the current database in the combobox at the top of the window in SSMS. You might want to find the database you created the procedure on by accident and drop it to avoid yourself or somebody else some confusion.